# Usage of <template> in front end development

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I was going through some tutorials for vue.js front end framework when i came across `<template>`tag being used in html code at a lot of places:

```
<template v-for="(choice,index) in choices">
    <h1>{{ choice }}</h1>
    <p>{{ index }}</p>
</template>
```

I wanted to know what exactly is the purpose of this element. Is it something usually used in front end development?

Comment: Using Vue?  Yes.

Comment: A nice explanation can be found here: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3216-template-vs-ng-container-for-grouping-dom-nodes-in-angular-2-4-4.htm

Comment: "On checking this with other html elements i found out that it works the same as div element" — No, it doesn't! http://jsbin.com/hebuzenite/1/edit?html,output

Comment: `<template>` lets you put structure in your templates, such as your `v-for` loop, that you don't need  represented as DOM nodes in the rendered product.  In your example, you could have used a div or a span in place of the template tag, but that would leave an unnecessary div or span wrapping each of your header/paragraph pairs.

Comment: (I missed my edit window, I should clarify that I was referring to Vue's `template` element, not the HTML5 element, which I believe is a slightly different thing.)

Comment: @DanielBeck so basically template lets me keep the DOM view in element inspector clean and view able?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The [`<template>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) in general

> The HTML Content Template (`<template>`) element is a mechanism for
> holding client-side content that is not to be rendered when a page is
> loaded but may subsequently be instantiated during runtime using
> JavaScript.
>
> Think of a template as a content fragment that is being stored for
> subsequent use in the document. While the parser does process the
> contents of the `<template>` element while loading the page, it does so
> only to ensure that those contents are valid; the element's contents
> are not rendered, however.

##The `<template>` element in Vue.js

You can find more information about it in the Vue.js guide. For example, in the context of [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-if).

> Conditionally render the element based on the truthy-ness of the expression value. The element and its contained directives / components are destroyed and re-constructed during toggles. **If the element is a `<template>` element, its content will be extracted as the conditional block.**

What that means exactly can be seen in this example:

```
<div v-if="true">Foo</div>
<template v-if="true">Bar</template>
```

which will result in:

```
<div>Foo</div>
Bar
```

The `<template>` element will not be part of the DOM after if has been processed by Vue.js anymore. The same applies when using the `v-for` directive on `<template>`.

Comment: Nice explanation in example.I didn't know template would render that way. Wouldn't the first way (using div) be the almost always favorable? .... Otherwise i will see something weird in the element inspector

Comment: @VSharma That depends on the use case. Sometimes you need the one, sometimes the other.

Answer (score 1):

[See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template):

> The HTML Content Template (`<template>`) element is a mechanism for
>   holding client-side content that is not to be rendered when a page is
>   loaded but may subsequently be instantiated during runtime using
>   JavaScript.
>
> Think of a template as a content fragment that is being stored for
>   subsequent use in the document. While the parser does process the
>   contents of the `<template>` element while loading the page, it does
>   so only to ensure that those contents are valid; the element's
>   contents are not rendered, however.

or [the HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/semantics-scripting.html#the-template-element):

> The template element is used to declare fragments of HTML that can be cloned and inserted in the document by script.
>
> In a rendering, the template element represents nothing.